# footer not staying to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I implemented a simple footer with css and bootstrap. It is working as expected on most pages except on pages that do not have a lot of content the footer will appear at the end of the content opposed to the bottom of the page
[image]

Spent a lot of time trying to figure it out but I just cant get it

```css
.footer {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        background:#dfdfdf;
        
    }
.body-tag {            
        height: 100%;
        background: #F6F6F6;
        color: #333333;
        margin-top: 5rem; 
        padding-bottom: 4rem;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body class="body-tag">
    <div class="footer fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <footer class="py-3 my-4">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">Features</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">Pricing</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">FAQs</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p class="text-center footer-text">&copy; name, Inc</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would suggest to simply create a new div where the content goes. Give that one a height of 100vh and the footer will stay at the bottom

Comment: It looks like your shown code is something completely different than the one in the example

Comment: The `fixed-bottom` class applies `position:fixed`, but here you are probably overwriting that with `relative` due to your `footer` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the footer Just remove unnecessary margin and padding from body and margin-bottom from footer

As per you diagram there shouldn't be any problem of footer placement, If there is any position value in footer remove it, and also this all should be have single parent.

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.body-tag {
  height: 100%;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  color: #333333;
}

/*Just Demo Purpose*/
nav{
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 60px;
}
main{
height:200vh;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body class="body-tag">
  <nav class="">
    <h1 class="text-center">Navbar</h1>
  </nav>
  <main></main>
  <footer class="footer py-3 ">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 footer-text">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="text-center footer-text">&copy; name, Inc</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: This works. Only issue is that with the view height on main it places the footer either way too low or too high on pages depending on how much content it has. Any way to correct this?

Comment: add all ur content inside main and give it a min-height of 100vh-120px, here 120px is footer height +header height

Comment: How would I go about doing this as the content in main differs from page to page?

Comment: When you give min-height as `calc( 100vh - 120px )`  then when there is less content it will remain the min-height and as the content increase the height increase and there by pushes the footer down. When you give just height there will not be space for large content.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed;` for your footer:

Here's an example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
  <footer>Hey i'm a footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, unfortunately nothing changed when implementing this.

Comment: That wouldn't change a thing though. The footer has a position of relative.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried previously, it does kind of work except it covers content on the page. I tried to give it padding but it didn't seem to do anything so i assume i was doing it the wrong way. I guess for each page i could just create a different class